# Question regarding minimum

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm wondering whether the following should be true. Suppose $f(t)$ is a real valued function (say, on $\mathbb{R}^n$) which attains its minimum at a unique point, say $x^*$ in the closure of a set $E$. If $x^*\notin E$, does $f$ not attain its minimum value in $E$?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean $f$'s minimum value in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is in $E$? Then, by your statement, the unique minimum is in $\bar{E} \setminus E$, meaning the said minimum is not achieved in $E$; otherwise it wouldn't be a unique minimum.

If you were saying that does $f$ have a minimum when restricted to $E$, then, yes, $f$ could have a minimum as shown below:

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $E = \{ \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Define $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = n$ if $x = \frac{1}{n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(x) = 0$ if $x=0$, and $f(x) = 2$ everywhere else. Then, the minimum of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is at $x=0$ which is in the closure of $E$. $f$ achieves a minimum of $1$ in $E$ at $x=1$.

I hope I did not completely butcher/misunderstand the problem.

Comment: No, I do not mean that. What I'm saying is the following. $f$ has a certain minimum value on $\text{cl}(E)$ and is attained by $x^*\in \text{cl}(E)$. $f$ may possibly have a different minimum value on $E$. What I'm claiming is that if $x^* \notin E$, then $f$ does not attain its minimum value in $E$. Assume $f$ is continuous etc.